# Why do I get the wrong answer from this C code?

Tags: c, for-loop, codeblocks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "simpio.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    float answer;
    int D;
    int N;
    int i=0;
    int p=1;

    printf("How much :");
    N=GetInteger();

    for (i=0; i!=N; i++)
    {
        for(p=1; p!=N; p++){
            D=1/p;
            answer+=D;
        }
    }

    printf("the answer is: %.2f",apotelesma);

    return 0;
}
```

for example if I gave N=100 then the program was suppose to
1/1+1/2+1/3....1/N
and then give me the 5.19
but for some reason its just skips it

I know it's an easy question I started programing like for two weeks ma trying to learn alone.

Comment: You are rounding `1/p` to an integer when you assign it to `D`. `D` is an `int`.

Comment: `answer` is on the stack and is not given an initial value, so it could start with _any_ value. Change `float answer;` to `float answer = 0;`

Comment: Also, per Szabolcs, do `float D;` Then, change `D = 1/p;` to `D = 1.0 / p;` to force floating point math rather than integer math [that would truncate to zero]

Comment: And of course the value output should be `answer`, not `apotelesma` which presumably is defined in `simpio.h`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: `apotelesma` is Greek for `result`, per [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/).  I think it is simply an incomplete conversion of the code from Greek to English — yes, it should be `answer`, but `apotelesma` is not defined elsewhere.

Comment: Why both `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include "stdio.h"`.  Including the same header twice is seldom constructive (though `<assert.h>` and X-Macros can be exceptions to that rule).  Use just the angle-bracket notation — `#include <stdio.h>` is correct and orthodox; `#include "studio."` is unorthodox and misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the inner-loop with this to force floating-point math:

```
for(p=1; p!=N; p++)
    answer += 1.0/p;
```

Also initialise `float answer = 0;`.

Comment: thanks I tried it and it was correct